# Why I'm not able to visit my tomcat server pages from phone with other domain name

Tags: tomcat, hosts, server.xml

Settings I have inside hosts file on windows 10:

```
ip_address domain_name 
#Where IP address = server IP address
#not my PC IP address
```

Settings I have inside server.xml file:

```xml
<Host name="www.domain_name.com"  appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
</Host>
```

From my PC when I run tomcat server I can call either:
ip_address:8080/site/ or domain_name.com:8080/site/ to visit page.
But from my phone works only ip_address:8080/site/.  Page can't be loaded when I call domain_name.com:8080/site/. What's wrong?

Comment: Your phone doesn't know about the domain name. You would need to edit its name resolution (e.g. a "hosts" file like on Windows) or add a name resolver that is used, i.e. a local DNS server.

Comment: Sorry @Hauke Ingmar Schmidt , I do not understand what you mean. Can you explain what is the steps? Do I need to make changes on my phone? or add some configuration on my PC or on tomcat server?

Comment: If you are on androd you will need to be root for editing `/system/etc/hosts` then just add `ip_adress domain_name`  .. If not as @HaukeIngmarSchmidt said you will have to add `A record` to a local dns.

Comment: if you have a terminal on your phone you can also use `--resolve` flag from cURL ex: `curl -s http://mydomain:8080 --resolve mydomain:8080:192.168.0.5`